# Python 3 Rock, Paper, Scissors

Tags: python, python-3.x, rock-paper-scissors

I've some basic knowledge of Python 3 and I've been working on the following code for some time now. I've been starting playing around OOP and external modules as you can see from the code. Any tips regarding the code are much appreciated.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import sys
import random
import re
import sqlite3

while True:

    class RockPaperScissors:
        def __init__(self): #Define __init__ method
            print("\n\nThis is a Rock, Paper, Scissors game where you can play against a computer. \nThe one who first gets three wins is the champion.\n")

        def menu(self): #Define menu method which displays the menu of the program
            user_input = input("--- MENU --- \nLogin & Play (1) \nCreate a New User (2) \nStatistics (3)\nExit game (4)\n\n")
            #The player is given an option to choose from four different options
            if user_input == "1":
                pass
            elif user_input == "2":
                self.new_user() #If the answer is '2', go to new_user method
            elif user_input == "3":
                self.statistics() #If the answer is '3', go to statistics method
            elif user_input == "4":
                print ("\nThanks for playing!")
                sys.exit() #If the answer is '4', end the running program
            else:
                print ("Please give a valid answer (1),(2),(3) or (4).\n")
                self.menu() #If the answer is invalid, return to menu method

        def player1_username(self): #Define player1_username method where player input a new username for their user
            database_connection = sqlite3.connect('test.db') #Connects to a 'test.db' database
            player1_username_input = input("Player 1, please give me your username: \n\n")
            self.player1_username_input = player1_username_input
            if not re.match("^[a-zA-Z0-9 _]*$", self.player1_username_input): #Checks that only letters, numbers or spaces are given
                print("Please enter a valid username using only letters, numbers and spaces.")
                database_connection.close() #Closes the connection to database
                self.player1_username() #Goes back to player1_username method if the username is invalid
            cursor = database_connection.execute("select exists(SELECT * from USERS where USERNAME = '{0}')".format(player1_username_input)) 
            for username in cursor: #Checks if the username exists in database 
                pass
            if username[0] == 1:
                pass
            elif username[0] == 0:
                print ("\nThe username was not found in the database. You must create a user if you haven't got one.\n")
                database_connection.close() #Closes the connection to database
                self.menu() #Returns to the menu if the username was not found in the database
            else:
                print("Something unexpected happened. Please try again")
                sys.exit()   

        def player1_password(self): #Define player1_password method where players input a password for their existing user
            database_connection = sqlite3.connect('test.db') #Connects to a 'test.db' database
            player1_password_input = input("Please give me your password: \n\n")
            if not re.match("^[a-zA-Z0-9 _]*$", player1_password_input): #Checks that only letters, numbers or spaces are given
                print("You can only enter a password with letters, numbers and spaces.")
                database_connection.close() #Closes the connection to database
                self.player1_password() #Goes back to player1_password method if the password is invalid
            cursor = database_connection.execute("select exists(SELECT * from USERS where PASSWORD = '{0}' AND USERNAME = '{1}')".format(player1_password_input,self.player1_username_input))
            for password in cursor: #Checks if the password matches to the given username in database
                pass
            if password[0] == 1:
                print ("Login successful ")
                database_connection.close() #Closes the connection to database if the login was successfull
            elif password[0] == 0:
                print ("The password doesn't match with the given username. Please try again.")
                self.player1_password() #If the password desn't match, the password is being asked again from the player
            else:
                print("Something unexpected happened. Please try again")
                sys.exit()

        def new_user(self): #Define new_user method where players can create a new user
            database_connection = sqlite3.connect('test.db') #Connects to a 'test.db' database
            new_user_username_input = input("Hi, please give me your new username. \n\n")
            if not re.match("^[a-zA-Z0-9 _]*$", new_user_username_input): #Checks that only letters, numbers or spaces are given
                print("Please enter a valid username. (Only letters and numbers allowed)")
                self.new_user() #Goes back to new_user method if the username is invalid
            cursor = database_connection.execute("select exists(SELECT * from USERS where USERNAME = '{0}')".format(new_user_username_input))
            for username in cursor:
                pass
            if username[0] == 1:
                print("This username is already taken. Please provide a different one.")
                self.new_user() #If the username is already taken, it goes back to new_user method
            elif username[0] == 0:
                pass
            else:
                print("Something unexpected happened. Please try again")
                sys.exit()    
            new_user_password_input = input("Please give me your new password. \n\n")
            if not re.match("^[a-zA-Z0-9 _]*$", new_user_password_input): #Checks that only letters, numbers or spaces are given
                print("Please enter a valid username and password combination. (Only letters and numbers allowed)")
                self.new_user() #Goes back to new_user method if the password is invalid
            print ("Creating new user... \n")
            database_connection.execute("INSERT INTO USERS (USERNAME,PASSWORD,WINS,LOSES,GAMESPLAYED,WINPERCENT) \
            VALUES ('{0}', '{1}',0,0,0,0)".format(new_user_username_input, new_user_password_input)); #Inserts the new user to the database
            database_connection.commit() #Performs a commit to the database
            database_connection.close() #Closes the connection to database
            print ("New user created successfully!\n")
            self.menu() #Returns to the menu method

        def statistics(self): #Define statistics method where statistics about the users are shown
            database_connection = sqlite3.connect('test.db') #Connects to a 'test.db' database
            print("Here are the top 10 players in the order, who has the highest winning percentage\n")
            order = database_connection.execute("SELECT USERNAME, WINS, LOSES, GAMESPLAYED, WINPERCENT FROM USERS ORDER BY WINPERCENT DESC LIMIT 10")
        #The query selects the top 10 users from database in the order that who has the highest winning percentage
            database_connection.commit() #Performs a commit to the database
            for row in order:
                print ("Username = ", row[0])
                print ("Wins = ", int(row[1]))
                print ("Loses = ", int(row[2]))
                print ("Games played = ", int(row[3]))
                print ("Winning percent = ", row[4], "\n");
            database_connection.close() #Closes the connection to database
            self.menu() #Returns to the menu method

        def win_messages(self): #Define win_messages method where the winning messages are shown after a win from one round of the game
            self.player1_win_message = ("Congrats {0}, you won computer in the game!".format(self.player1_username_input))
            self.computer_win_message = ("Too bad {0}, computer won you in the game!".format(self.player1_username_input))
            self.player1_games_won = 0 #Initializes the player1_games_won variable
            self.computer_games_won = 0 #Initializes the computer_games_won variable

        def player1_congrats(self): #Define player1_congrats method where the winning message for player1 is shown after winning three rounds against computer
            database_connection = sqlite3.connect('test.db') #Connects to a 'test.db' database
            print ("Gongrats {0}, you are the champion!\n".format(self.player1_username_input)) #Displays a winning message for player1
            database_connection.execute("UPDATE USERS set WINS = WINS + 1 where USERNAME = '{0}'".format(self.player1_username_input));
            database_connection.execute("UPDATE USERS set GAMESPLAYED = WINS + LOSES where USERNAME = '{0}'".format(self.player1_username_input));
            database_connection.execute("UPDATE USERS set WINPERCENT = WINS/GAMESPLAYED*100 where USERNAME = '{0}'".format(self.player1_username_input));
        #The querys above update the WINS, LOSES, GAMESPLAYED and WINPERCENT tables in the database
            database_connection.commit() #Performs a commit to the database
            database_connection.close() #Closes the connection to database

        def computer_congrats(self): #Define computer_congrats method
            database_connection = sqlite3.connect('test.db') #Connects to a 'test.db' database
            print ("Too bad {0}, computer is the champion!\n".format(self.player1_username_input)) #Displays a winning message for computer
            database_connection.execute("UPDATE USERS set LOSES = LOSES + 1 where USERNAME = '{0}'".format(self.player1_username_input));
            database_connection.execute("UPDATE USERS set GAMESPLAYED = WINS + LOSES where USERNAME = '{0}'".format(self.player1_username_input));
            database_connection.execute("UPDATE USERS set WINPERCENT = WINS/GAMESPLAYED*100 where USERNAME = '{0}'".format(self.player1_username_input));
        #The querys above update the WINS, LOSES, GAMESPLAYED and WINPERCENT tables in the database
            database_connection.commit() #Performs a commit to the database
            database_connection.close() #Closes the connection to database

        def new_game(self): #Define new_game method where player1 is being asked to play another round
            self.new_game_choice = str.lower(str.strip(input("Do you want to play another round? (yes/no)\n\n")))
            if self.new_game_choice == "yes":                
                print("Great!\n\n") #If the player chooses 'yes', the program is started again
            elif self.new_game_choice == "no":
                print("Thanks for playing!")
                sys.exit() #Exit the running program
            else:
                print("Please enter a yes or no as an answer")
                self.new_game() #Call the new_game method again if the answer is invalid

        def player1_choice(self): #Define player1_choice method asks the player1's input in the choice between rock, paper and scissors
            self.player1_guess = str.lower(str.strip(input("So {0} rock, paper or scissors?\n\n".format(self.player1_username_input))))   
            if self.player1_guess == "rock":
                self.player1_num = 1
            elif self.player1_guess == "paper":
                self.player1_num = 2
            elif self.player1_guess == "scissors":
                self.player1_num = 3
            else:
                print ("Please only insert rock, paper or scissors as an answer!")
                self.player1_choice() #Call the p1_choice method again if the answer is invalid

        def computer_choice(self): #Define computer_choice method defined what option the computer chooses based on a random number
            self.computer_num = random.randrange(1,4)
            if self.computer_num == 1:
                print("The computer chose rock")
            elif self.computer_num == 2:
                print("The computer chose paper")
            elif self.computer_num == 3:
                print("The computer chose scissors")

        def results(self): #Define results method the displays what the current results are for the game
            difference = self.computer_num - self.player1_num
            if difference == 0:
                print ("It's a tie!")
            elif difference % 3 == 1: #If the computer won the round, the difference is 1
                self.computer_games_won+=1
                print (self.computer_win_message)
            elif difference % 3 == 2: #If the user won the round, the difference is 2
                self.player1_games_won+=1
                print (self.player1_win_message)
            print ("So far {0} has won {1} times, and computer has won {2} times".format(self.player1_username_input,self.player1_games_won,self.computer_games_won))              


    user = RockPaperScissors()
    user.menu()
    user.player1_username()
    user.player1_password()
    user.win_messages()
    user.player1_choice()
    user.computer_choice()
    user.results() 
    while True:
        if user.player1_games_won == 3: #If the player 1 won three rounds against computer, call the player1_congrats method
            user.player1_congrats()
            user.new_game()
            break
        elif user.computer_games_won == 3: #If the computer won three rounds against user, call the ccomputer_congrats method
            user.computer_congrats()
            user.new_game()
            break
        else: #If either has yet won three rounds go back to player1_choice, computer_choice and results methods
            user.player1_choice() 
            user.computer_choice()
            user.results()
```

Comment: I would recommend you use comments to say why you're doing something. Not what you're doing. Let the code itself say what you're doing. Try and make use of descriptive variable and method names where possible to achieve this, these can be just as helpful as a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several major issues in the code:

- **don't string-format SQL-queries** - it is seriously error-prone and dangerous - your code is vulnerable to *SQL injection attacks*. Instead, use [parameterized queries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1633589/771848) - pass parameters in a second argument to `.execute()`
- [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) violation - there is a lot of code duplication. For instance, you can connect to a database once, remember the database connection and a cursor in an instance variable and reuse
- avoid [God-object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object) like classes. Your `RockPaperScissors` is responsible for too many things at once. Try to break it apart into logical pieces - e.g. move all database interaction specific logic into a separate class or utility functions